# What is the right procedure to modify on pug a parameter passed from express?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Let's say I am passing a parameter n from express to pug, what is the procedure to modify it within the pug file?
Example:

```
router.get("/chat", (req, res) => {
 let n = 2;
 res.render("chat", { csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), n: n })

});
```

And somewhere on the pug page I want to do something like:

```
- for(var m=4; m>=0; m--)
  - !{n} = !{n}+1
```

Writing this on pug, the page is not loading, as if the parameter n isn't defined.
How can I do it? I haven't found an answer on the web yet.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a look at the help section on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) here.  Specifically, you need to ask something that shows you have made an attempt and what's going wrong.  "How do I do it?" is not what SO is for.  Why does the code above fail?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Certainly you can execute code in pug templates as detailed in the [official documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html)

Comment: Thank you for the documentation, unfortunately there is nothing about this topic in there. One of my attempts is the code above, it fails not loading the pug page, as if there isn't such a parameter declared in the file. I am trying to modify on pug a parameter passed from express.

Comment: I am going to add how the code fails in the question and I will read the help section